# DbContext.Database.SetCommandTimeout is not working as expected in ef core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have simple code where I want the query to timeout to test my exception logging, hence I am using the `context.Database.SetCommandTimeout()` method, supplying the minimal value of 1 tick, but the query does not time out and fetches the data from the database.

My EF version is EF Core 3.1.8.

The code looks like this:

```
await using var context = new CriusCommissionsDatabaseContext(_config);
context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1));
var saleSegments = await context.BSaleSegment 
                                .Include(x => x.Sale)
                                .Where(x => x.Sale.CorrelationId == correlationId)
                                .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

When running the `SetCommandTimeout` function in the [RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/2ff3db33660c59e35d449dcbddd8d37dfba72b7b/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs) what happens in in the function is that the TimeSpan is converted to an integer and `TimeSpan.FromTicks(1)` will be converted to `0`. According to the [DbCommand.CommandTimoout Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtimeout) it has the following remarks

> Note to implementers, it is recommended that 0 means no timeout.

So in this case it means TimeSpan.FromTicks(1) == no timeout, so the minimal value you would be able to enter would have to be equal to int 1.